# Can anyone help me to write sql statement?

Tags: mysql, sql

Can anyone help me to write sql below?

Suppose:

**tbl_request**

```
No       Title       Date           Priority
1        AAA         2013-08-06     3
2        BBB         2013-08-04     1
3        CCC         2013-08-05     0
4        DDD         2013-08-02     4
5        EEE         2013-08-01     2
6        FFF         2013-08-04     0
7        GGG         2013-08-03     5
8        HHH         2013-08-03     0
```

There are two top priorities to order in sql statement:

- 1st priority: Ordering by Priority in Ascending (only 1,2,3,4,5)
- 2nd priority: Ordering by Date Descending

I want to show all request that order with the 1st priority first (0 won't display). After 1st priority, i want to display the 2nd priority.

**Here is what i want:**

```
No       Title       Date           Priority
2        BBB         2013-08-04     1
5        EEE         2013-08-01     2
1        AAA         2013-08-06     3
4        DDD         2013-08-02     4
7        GGG         2013-08-03     5
3        FFF         2013-08-05     0
6        GGG         2013-08-04     0
8        HHH         2013-08-03     0
```

I don't know how to write sql statement to get the format above. Can anyone tell me how to write it?

Thank in advance.

Comment: *"I want to show all request that order with the 1st priority first (0 won't display)."* This is quite confusing as your example actually *show* the priority 0 in your result set.

Answer (score 2):

How about something like

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1
ORDER BY 
  CASE WHEN `Priority` != 0 THEN NULL ELSE 1 END,
  `Priority`,
  `Date` DESC
```

or

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1
ORDER BY 
  CASE WHEN `Priority` != 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END,
  `Priority`,
  `Date` DESC
```

### [SQL Fiddle DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1a551/4)

This will ensure that even if any of the priorities are greater than the other answers max values, this will still sort 0 as last.

Comment: Great. I think we can also use `0` instead of `NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `case` expression as below

```
select No,Title,Date,Priority
from tab
order by 
  case
     when Priority=0 then 9999
     else Priority
  end,
  Date desc
```

Comment: What if `Priority` has more than 9999 priority? (e.g. 0 to 15000)

Comment: @hims056 Than OP should expanded it to bigger value

Comment: Then the query is static.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like:-

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_request
    WHERE Priority IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
    ORDER BY Priority, DATE DESC
UNION
SELECT * FROM tbl_request
    WHERE Priority NOT IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
    ORDER BY Date DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select no,title,date,priority
from tbl_request
order by if(priority=0,99999,priority),date desc
```

This assumes that no priority is over 99999. Yo also need to pit back quotes around no and date columns - I don't have them on this keyboard!

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't displaying `0` Priority records, then the below SQL statement will do just fine.

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_request WHERE Priority <> 0 ORDER BY Priority ASC, Date DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select * from tbl_request 
Order by ( CASE WHEN Priority > 0 THEN Priority ELSE 99999999 END ), DATE DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
Select title, date, priority from tbl_request Order By IF(priority = 0, 99999, priority) asc, date desc
```

though it is ugly, inefficient, it works for you. Or you can consider making a union of to sub queries

```
Select title, date, priority from tbl_request where priority > 0 order by priority asc
union
Select title, date, priority from tbl_request where priority = 0 order by date desc
```

Comment: union ALL !! Never waste the precious time :) Here there's no danger you will select intersecting rows.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1
ORDER BY 
  (CASE WHEN Priority = 0 THEN  9999 ELSE 1 END)  asc, date desc
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1
ORDER BY field(`Priority`,0),`Priority`,
  `Date` DESC
```

**[FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1a551/10)**